# break the data into small groups based on the target continous value?

Tags: machine-learning

I am facing a challenge with my data, and I am not sure how to resolve it.

I have a dataset $D$ that it has target value as a regression problem, the following shows the Regressor value:

[image]

I need to :

- train a model in an episodic format, then I need to divide the data into sample the data points $X$ and their corresponding target $Y$ (the value in above picture) into many subsets of the dataset ($D_1, D_2,\dots, D_M$, also called tasks) based on this target value.
  For example in [this sinusoidal function](https://github.com/vinit97/Few-Shot-Regression-Meta-Learning), they sample amplitude/slope from the [`0.1, 5]`, phase shift from `[0, 2pi]` and vertical shift `[0, 3]`, for sampling each periodic or polynomial task respectively.

But my challenge is different. The question is:

1. Is there any statistical technique to divide the data into $M$ subsets (tasks) based on the target continuous value, where the samples' target values within each task are correlated but their values are independent from the other tasks (i.e., sub-dataset)?

This means a **high correlation of intra task** target values and **relatively lower inter-task correlation**.

Comment: It seems like you are describing clustering. How it is not clustering?

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle images as you have included

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your comment. Clustering based on target values? because the input is the string, and the output is the values mentioned above.

Comment: There's no such a thing in clustering as “target value”, you can cluster whatever data.